# secureTextEntry for separate part -- swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have changed a string in a label with `secureTextEntry = true`with "••••••••••••••". It works perfect, but how I could change the whole string except last 4 characters in the string?

Comment: So, you want all the characters to be "•", except for the last 4?

Comment: Are you applying the string to UILabel or to UITextField?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The case here would depend on how you use this string: in a UILabel, or in a UITextField. Either way, the best thing here would be to do the following by extending String like so:

```
extension String {

    init(withSecureShowOnlyLast4 values : String) {
        self.init()
        let array = [Character](values.characters)
        if array.count <= 4 {
            self = values
        } else {
            var first = array.count - 4
            var lastFour : [Character] = []
            while first <= (array.count - 1) {
                lastFour.append(array[first])
                first += 1
            }
            self = String(Array(repeating: "•", count: array.count - 4) + lastFour)
        }
    }

}



let pass : String = "fesnjufodpsk"

let obfs = String(withSecureShowOnlyLast4: pass) //prints : ••••••••dpsk
```

Depending on how you need this, this is how i'd use it:

**UILABEL :**

Here's a custom class to ensure the safe keeping of the data you want.

```
class SafeLabel : UILabel {

    var makeSafe : Bool = false
    private var safeKey : String?
    private var alternateSet = Bool()

    override var text: String? {
        didSet {
            if makeSafe && !alternateSet {
                alternateSet = true
                safeKey = text
                self.text = nil
            } else if alternateSet {
                alternateSet = false
            }
        }

        willSet {
            if makeSafe && !alternateSet {
                self.safeKey = text
            }
        }
    }

    var safe : String {
        get {
            guard let sa = safeKey else {
                return ""
            }
            guard makeSafe else {
                return sa
            }
            return String(withSecureShowOnlyLast4: sa)
        }
    }
}   
let lab = SafeLabel()

lab.makeSafe = true

lab.text = "9j3od3dkuhosfg"

print(lab.safe) //prints ••••••••••osfg
```

Note the use of .makeSafe, which removes the printing and use of the data all together (without deleting it).

**FOR UITEXTFIELD :**

For this class i would use the `textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool` method to modify the string. Here again, i'd subclass the TextField like so, and change up the protected string like this:

```
class SafeField : UITextField {

    var makeSafe : Bool = false
    private var safeKey : String?
    private var alternateSet = Bool()

    override var text: String? {
        didSet {
            if makeSafe && !alternateSet {
                alternateSet = true
                safeKey = text
                self.text = nil
            } else if alternateSet {
                alternateSet = false
            }
        }

        willSet {
            guard text != nil else {
                if let t = safeKey, t.characters.count == 1 || t.isEmpty {
                    self.safeKey = nil
                } else {
                    isDeletingEntry()
                }
                return
            }
            if makeSafe && !alternateSet, let t = text {
                if let s = safeKey {
                    self.safeKey = s + t
                } else {
                    self.safeKey = t
                }
            }
        }
    }

    var safe : String {
        get {
            guard let sa = safeKey else {
                return ""
            }
            guard makeSafe else {
                return sa
            }
            return String(withSecureShowOnlyLast4: sa)
        }
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
    }

    private func isDeletingEntry() {
        if let old = safeKey {
            let new = String(old.characters.dropLast())
            self.text = new
        }
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}


class View: UIView, UITextFieldDelegate {
    //Of course, this can be a ViewController, or anything that can handle the 
    //code bellow
    var safe : SafeField = {
        var s = SafeField()
        s.makeSafe = true
        return s
    }()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        addSubview(safe)
        safe.frame = .zero
        safe.delegate = self
    }

    func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

        guard safe != textField else {

            if string.characters.isEmpty {
                safe.text = nil
            } else {
                safe.text = string
            }

            return false
        }

        return true
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

}
```

Obviously here you need to use `safe` instead of `text` when retrieving the value since `text` is always hardcoded to `nil`, which i assume should not be an issue considering that obfuscated labels are always a minority in UI dev. To get the value from the TextField, you would need to set the makeSafe variable to false in order to retrieve the unobfuscated value of your string. With security as the main focus, the advantage here is that you can set your code to set and unset the makeSafe variable anywhere on a per-need basis, without having to worry about something or someone accessing it's value directly from another file.

Of course, if you're using a keyboard element, or some kind of protocol to modify a UILabel directly, just swap out the text variable for SafeLabel's with the one in SafeField. (If you are using custom protocols, make sure to check the label is indeed a SafeLabel by optional casting :

```
    func protocolMethod(label: UILabel, doSomething: Bool) {
       guard let lab = label as? SafeLabel else {
         //do your stuff
         return 
       }
   //Here you can manipulate lab as a SafeLabel and modify it according to the SafeLabel SubClass
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can drop `label.isSecureTextEntry = true`, and instead use:

```
var string = label.text!
var result = String()

if string.characters.count > 4{
    for i in 1...string.characters.count - 4{
        result += "•"
    }
    string = string[string.index(string.startIndex, offsetBy: string.characters.count-4)..<string.endIndex]
    string = result + string
}

label.text = string
```